# Are there Lie algebra ideals with proper radical?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over $\mathrm{k}$

1. Ideal $P$ of $L$ is called prime if $[H, K] \subseteq P$ with $H, K$ ideals of $L$ implies $H \subseteq P$ or $K \subseteq P$
2. The radical of ideal M is definied by $\sqrt{M}=\cap\{P \subseteq L: \mathrm{P} \text { is prime ideal containing } M\}$

> My Question:
> Are there Lie algebra ideals with proper radical?

> Update:- For $L=gl_n \oplus S$ where $S$ is any simple Lie algebra.

> The ideals are $0, S, Z, Z+S, s l_{n}, s l_{n}+S,$ $g l_{n}$ and $L,$ where $Z$ is the centre of $g l_{n}$.

$L, gl_n, Z+S$ are the prime ideals only, therefore $\sqrt{sl_n}=L \cap  gl_n =gl_n$.

$0$ is not prime ideal because $[S,gl_n]=0 \subseteq 0 $ but  neither $S \subseteq 0$ nor $gl_n \subseteq 0$

$S$ is not prime ideal because $[Z,gl_n]=0 \subseteq S $ but  neither $Z \subseteq S$ nor $gl_n \subseteq S$

$Z$ is not prime ideal because $[S,gl_n]=0 \subseteq Z $ but  neither $S \subseteq Z$ nor $gl_n \subseteq Z$

$sl_n$ is not prime ideal because $[S,gl_n]=0 \subseteq sl_n $ but  neither $S \subseteq sl_n$ nor $gl_n \subseteq sl_n$

$sl_n + S $ is not prime ideal because $[S+Z,gl_n +S]=S \subseteq sl_n+S  $ but  neither $S+Z \subseteq sl_n + S$ nor $gl_n +S \subseteq sl_n + S$

Is all this true?? I appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper"?

Comment: I mean that $\sqrt{M} \neq L   $ and $\sqrt{M} \neq M   $

Comment: Does $sl_n+Z$ is an ideal ?

Comment: I don't think that $sl_n+Z$ is an ideal ?
Because all ideals in $L$ must be in the form $A+B$ where $A$ is an ideal of $S$ and $B$ is an ideal of $gl_n$ ? what is your openion Mr @TorstenSchoeneberg ??

Comment: $sl_n+Z = gl_n$. Actually, in hindsight it might be more conceptual to write my example as $Z \oplus S_1 \oplus S_2$ where the $S_i$ are simple LAs and $Z$ is any non-zero abelian LA. I just took $S_1 =sl_n$ and $Z$ one-dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a simple Lie algebra $S$ and set $L:=\mathfrak{gl}_n \oplus S$, $M:=\mathfrak{sl}_n\oplus 0$. Then $M \subsetneq \sqrt{M} \subsetneq L$.

Comment: Does $M:=\mathfrak{sl}_n\oplus 0=\mathfrak{sl}_n$ ? What is $\sqrt{M}$ equal?
I cant find the prime ideals to take its intersection.

Comment: Sorry but if you cannot identify the ideals and prime ideals of the Lie algebra I wrote down, I find it hard to imagine how you could evaluate any answer to your question. Do you understand what a direct sum of Lie algebras is?

Comment: I understand that direct sum is sum with zero intersection, $gl_n$ has only four ideals and $S$ has only tow ideal 0 and $S$ itself.
Is this false

Comment: Direct sum of Lie algebras $L_1 \oplus L_2$ means more than just zero intersection, namely, that the two summands commute, i.e. $[L_1, L_2]=0$. The other things you write are correct. Now quite generally, how can we describe the ideals of a direct sum in terms of the ideals of the summands?

Comment: The ideals are $0 +0=0$, $0+S=S$, $Z+0=Z$, $Z+S$, $sl_n + 0= sl_n$, $sl_n + S$ $gl_n + 0 = gl_n$ and $gl_n + S =L$, where $Z$ is the centre of $gl_n$.
Is this false ?? @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: But, which of them are prime?
I know that $L$ itself is prime and $0+0=0$ is not prime.

Comment: I do new update, see it please .

Comment: Looks good now.

Comment: Thanks to your guidance.